How to get a query result in List<Object[]> type in orm.xml with JPA?
I'm trying to get a query result in List<Object[]> type by a named native query, which is defined at the orm.xml.
When I run the code, it gives me an error as following:

Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type

Here's the orm.xml
<named-native-query name="UserInfo.findByCompCode" result-set-mapping="tmp">
    <query>
        SELECT
            A.USER_ID
            , B.USER_AREA_CODE
        FROM
             USER A
             , USER_DETAIL B
        WHERE
             A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
             AND A.COMP_CODE = '01'
    <query>
</named-native-query>
<sql-result-set-mapping name="tmp">
     <column-result name="USER_ID" />
     <column-result name="USER_AREA_CODE" />
</sql-result-set-mapping>

The return type of the repository is List<Object[]>.
How can I get the query result in List<Object[]> type?
Thanks in advance

The JPA query will return one Object[] per row the SQL query returns. If you only expect one row, don't use getResultList - use getSingleResult() instead .
Since you are getting issues, maybe show the repository code you are using - I don't really know if spring handles returning just an Object[] in how it wraps JPA, so you might be better off just getting hte list and using get(0) on it, or trying projection to wrap these values into a custom object instead of object[]

I expect a list of Object[] and the return type of the repository is also List<Object[]>.

Why Did you define a result-set-mapping? those are used to define return types and mappings - in this case it is probably being interpreted as returning List, so that the column names are returned with the values. You need to show your Spring setup to be sure (or just use Tuple instead of Object[])
